# This python code calls a function that returns a value but user input is asked twice

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code but its asking me input two times.I just want the function "grades" to be called and which will return value according to user input. But when I execute this code,it asks for user input two times.

```
def grades(score):

 try:
        score = float(input("enter the score please"))
 except:
        score = -1
 if score<0.0 or score>1.0:
      return "Wrong score"
 elif score==0.9:
      return "A"
 elif score==0.8:
      return "B"
 elif score==0.7:
      return "C"
 elif score==0.6:
      return "D"
 elif score==0.5:
      return "B"
 else :
      return "F"

MyScore=float(input("enter my score"))
result=grades(MyScore)
print(result)
```

I want the function "grades" to be called but the user input should be asked only once.

Comment: You are using input twice!! Remove line MyScore=... And use grades without parameters

Comment: remove try-except part from `grades`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the function grades you're asking for the score:

```
score = float(input("enter the score please"))
```

and then outside of the function, you're also doing it:

```
MyScore=float(input("enter my score"))
```

Remove one of the two input statements, and it will only ask you the one time :)

```
def grades(score):

 if score<0.0 or score>1.0:
      return "Wrong score"
 elif score==0.9:
      return "A"
 elif score==0.8:
      return "B"
 elif score==0.7:
      return "C"
 elif score==0.6:
      return "D"
 elif score==0.5:
      return "B"
 else :
      return "F"


try:
        score = float(input("enter the score please"))
except:
        score = -1

result=grades(score)
print(result)'
```

Comment: I tried but still the same problem. I want to write a program to prompt for a score between 0.0 and 1.0. If the
score is out of range, print an error message. If the score is between 0.0 and 1.0,
print a grade using the following table:

if Score>= 0.9  then Grade=  A,
if Score>= 0.8  then Grade=  B,
if Score>= 0.7  then Grade=   C,
if Score>= 0.6  then Grade=  D,
if Score< 0.6    then Grade=  F,


I want to accomplish this by using a function
called GRADING that takes a score as its parameter and returns a grade
as a string.
can you please help me write this code?

Comment: @Rohail Check the original answer - I updated it with a solution

Comment: @ J. Murray Thank you so much